# "Add more" directives loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the right way for adding directives in a "add more" button?
I have a directive that renders html. it works fine when just using it in a templateUrl.
Now i want to let the user load more of the same directive with a "add more" button
What is the right way doing so?

Comment: Not clear what you tried or where you are stuck please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Have an array of things on your scope and a function to add a thing:

```
$scope.things = [ { id: 1, name: 'thing 1' }, 
    { id: 2, name: 'thing 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'thing 3' }
];

$scope.addThing = function(){
    $scope.things.push( { id: 4, 'thing 4' } );
}
```

In the view the list of things can be displayed using the ngRepeat directive:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat='thing in things' thingy='thing'><my-directive>
```

and the button to add more things:

```
<button type='button' ng-click='addThing()'>Add a thing</button>
```

Comment: How would u suggest i do the fadeing in?
Now when i push the item, it get shown right away with no fading affect

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations which describes using jQuery animation or angular and CSS.

Comment: how can i add a class only to the new item i'm pushing? if i had a class in the directive, it will fire up the items already on the screen.

Comment: Look at the section that says 'How they work'. It explains that angular adds the class ng-enter to newly added items. So if you had a class called 'thing' you could add a CSS rule targeting .thing.ng-enter

Answer (score -1):

As always, i think i found an answer 2 minutes after posting...
Here my controller

```
.controller('LatestMovementsCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
   $scope.load_more = function() {
   var newElement = $compile( '<my-directive line="data1" class="balance_item_main"></my-directive>' )( $scope );
    jQuery('#load_more_data').append(newElement.hide().fadeIn(1000));
  }
})
```

If any 1 has a better solution i would love to hear about it

Comment: No DOM manipulation in controllers should include code with your ?

Comment: i didn't understand your question. could you explain it better?

Comment: ah sorry used ? in place of the word question... that didn't make it clear.  Just saying you shouldn't manipulate DOM elements from within a controller in Angular DOM manipulation should only be done within directives.  Gruff Bunny's answer shows the more angular way of doing things.  You have a model that is bound from the view and the controller/model isn't aware of the view at all (this way controller can be tested and re-used despite the view).